# Can a type be set globally using inner/outer and be replaceable?

Tags: modelica, units-of-measurement, openmodelica, systemmodeler

### Problem Description

I would like to use Non-SI-Units for time in economical modeling (e.g. System Dynamics). While of course I could go for *seconds* (*s*) and then use `displayUnit` there is to my knowledge no nice way to modify *displayUnit* for *time* in System Modeler, which I am mainly using.

So, writing a library I would like the user to make a choice of a global `type` called `ModelTime` which ideally would be declared as `inner` and `replaceable` at some top-level class. Then any component within a model could use the global `type` to consistently treat any time-related vars.

### Minimal Example

The following example shows how I would like to implement this.

- `package Units` declares two Non-SI Unit types( `Time_year`, `Time_month`)
- `package Interfaces` contains a partial model class `GenericSimulationModel` which will be the top-level scope for any model written using the library. It is supposed to provide the `type ModelTime` as an `inner` and `replaceable` class
- `package Components` defines a simple `block` class that uses `ModelTime` via an `outer` definition to define its `output y` that simple shows `time` in the globally chosen units of time
- `model Example` ties all of this together to provide an example how any model using the library should work out

Here is the code:

```
model MinimalExample

  package Units
    type Time_year = Real(final quantity = "Time", final unit = "yr");    
    type Time_month = Real(final quantity = "Time", final unit = "mo");
  end Units;

  package Interfaces
    partial model GenericSimulationModel "Top-level model scope providing global vars"
      inner replaceable type ModelTime = Years "Set to : Months, Years";
    protected
      type Years = Units.Time_year;
      type Months = Units.Time_month;
    end GenericSimulationModel;
  end Interfaces;

  package Components
    block ComponentUsingTime
      outer type ModelTime = MinimalExample.Units.Time_year;
      output ModelTime y;
    equation
      y = time;
    end ComponentUsingTime;
  end Components;

  model Example
    extends Interfaces.GenericSimulationModel(
      redeclare replaceable type ModelTime = Months
    );
    Components.ComponentUsingTime c;
  end Example;
equation

end MinimalExample;
```

While everything compiles without error in System Modeler and OpenModelica, it unfortunately does not work out:  The redeclared type is not used within the component c in the `Example` model given above.

**What can I do to achieve what I want to do?**

Comment: I crossposted this question on Wolfram Community (cf. [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1700660?p_p_auth=6q86Modr)).

Comment: OpenModelica allows to set the display unit by choosing "Simulation Time Unit" in the pltting view. Is that not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received some [feedback on Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1700660?p_p_auth=6q86Modr) from someone at Wolfram MathCore (developers of the System Modeler):

> *The behavior you see for MinimalExample.example and MinimalLibrary.Example are bugs, and from what I can see they should work, I have forwarded them to a developer working on these things.*